# Why doesn't my Delphi function get my comm ports from the registry?

Tags: registry, delphi-xe3

My code:

```
procedure EnumCommPorts(aStrings: TStrings);
var
  Registry: TRegistry;
begin
  Registry := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    Registry.OpenKey('hardware\devicemap\serialcomm', False);
    Registry.GetKeyNames(aStrings);
  finally
    Registry.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EnumCommPorts(Memo1.Lines);
end;
```

The screenshot below shows that there are 2 comm ports defined:

[image]

However, when I click the button Memo1 remains empty. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of mistakes.

First of all you are attempting to open the registry with write access. You won't get that as a standard user, with UAC enabled, under HKLM.

And secondly you call `GetKeyNames` by mistake. That returns the names of all sub-keys. The `SERIALCOMM` node has no sub-keys. Just so that you are clear, the `DEVICEMAP` node has five sub-keys, one of which is `SERIALCOMM`. You need to call `GetValueNames`.

This code will work:

```
Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
Registry.OpenKeyReadOnly('hardware\devicemap\serialcomm');
Registry.GetValueNames(aStrings);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Do you also know how to get the data ("COM7", "COM9") from this. It seem TRegistry doesn't know the method `GetValue`, which I thought would do the trick.

Comment: `Value := Registry.ReadString(Name)` where `Value` is a string, and `Name` is the value name, e.g. `\Device\USBSER000`

Comment: OK, I got my comm port numbers :-). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.GetCommList(cbx:TComboBox);
var
  reg: TRegistry;
  st: Tstrings;
  i: Integer;
begin
  reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    cbx.Clear;
    reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('hardware\devicemap\serialcomm');
    st := TstringList.Create;
    try
      reg.GetValueNames(st);
      for i := 0 to st.Count - 1 do
        cbx.Items.Add(reg.Readstring(st.strings[i]));
    finally
      st.Free;
    end;
    reg.CloseKey;
  finally
    reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: While this code may well work, a good answer would include an explanation of how it works and why it is a good solution.